# How to send data to an ESP32 with as little delay as possible from an Android app

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, esp8266, wifi, android

I have an ESP32 module. I want to send data to it using an Android app.

I tried using http but the delay is big especially since I want to send about 20 values per second with a delay between 50 to 100 ms.

So I am looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: How are you sending it exactly ? bluetooth? wi-fi? WHAT are you sending ? How big ? what app build ? how are you RECIEVING it ? SPI ? i2c ? there can be SOOO many variables that are not necessarily about the module itself that could influence the setup.

Comment: i am sending very small data just one asci character 
i tried wifi with http request

Comment: http request it self takes time to be sent from the app 
So i am looking for a faster way to send without delay

Comment: @AhmedSalman that doesn't sound like an electrical engineering problem but like an Android development problem. You've already mentioned one part of your stack – HTTP – which seems to be a very bad choice for low latency. It seems you haven't really researched much at all in the direction of what HTTP does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is fundamentally about software-centric issues of network protocols and Android application development, and not about Electrical Engineering.  If you had something that worked to a PC but not to the ESP32, then with *full details provided* that might just barely be on topic here; but the present question is not.  Likely the subject belongs on stackoverflow, but the question is too incomplete to be answerable, so migrating it would be a violation of the policy against migrating unanswerable questions.

Comment: Do note that if you can *timestamp* your data, then perhaps the exact time when it moves between systems can be less important.

Comment: "please migrate it to Arduino SE – Juraj 4 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Comment: @Juraj I see nothing about this question that is related to Arduino, so it will be likely closed on that site too.

Comment: @W5VO, it has the arduino tag. he programs esp32 with arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plain TCP sockets communication. Don't send the HTTP strings, send only byte. Let the connection open and reuse it to send the bytes. Check the state of the connection and when it disconnects reconnect.

Modify the receiving server side socket in app to receive only the bytes and keep the socket open.

Other option is to use UDP.

Comment: that's was really helpfull